# IE 11 Scrollbar float to top issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, scrollbar

I would like to ask about the handling of IE scrollbar.

The container is fix size and the items inside are longer than the container. For IE, AUTOHIDE scrollbar is needed.

Also, an overlay will float on the container.

The html is shown below:

```css
        .container {
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            overflow: hidden;
            overflow-y: auto;
            -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
        
        .container .item {
            border: 1px solid lightgrey;
            line-height: 50px;
        }
        
        .overlay {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 150px;
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            background-color: red;
        }
```

```html
 <div class='container'>
        <div class='item'>Item 1</div>
        <div class='item'>Item 2</div>
        <div class='item'>Item 3</div>
        <div class='item'>Item 4</div>
        <div class='item'>Item 5</div>
        <div class='item'>Item 6</div>
        <div class='item'>Item 7</div>
        <div class='item'>Item 8</div>
        <div class='item'>Item 9</div>
        <div class='item'>Item 10</div>
        <div class='item'>Item 11</div>
        <div class='item'>Item 12</div>
        <div class='item'>Item 13</div>
        <div class='item'>Item 14</div>
        <div class='item'>Item 15</div>
        <div class='item'>Item 16</div>
        <div class='item'>Item 17</div>
        <div class='item'>Item 18</div>
        <div class='item'>Item 19</div>
        <div class='item'>Item 20</div>
    </div>
    <div class='overlay'></div>
```

The autohide is worked fine, but it seems the scrollbar ignore the z-index and always float on the top when i mouseover to the list.

[image]

May i know is there any solution to control the issue? Or reduce the floating time? The best behaviour i expected it is the same as Chrome.

Thanks all!

Comment: you dont want to show scroll???

Comment: I want the scollbar if the overlap does not exist. If there is a element with higher z-index, i hope the scrollbar should not show as it has lower z-index. (Same as Chrome)

Comment: what do you mean??? the is a senario that overlap does not shown??

Comment: If overlay does not exist, when mouseover to the list and scroll, the scrollbar appear, after mouse leave for a while, the scrollbar disappear; If overlay exist, the scrollbar will not exist because it is hide by overlay, but it is scrollable

Comment: do you have more code when i run it i see no scroll even when over

Comment: do you try `z-index:-1`??

Comment: All code is display here, but i'm sorry that i forgot to mention that my case is IE 11. I updated the title.

Comment: Tested: I set z-index: -1 to .container, but still not work

Comment: use `z-index: -1` and `position:relative`

Comment: tell me if it helps

Comment: Tested: Add z-index: -1; position: relative; to .container. The scrollbar will not appear, but the list become unscrollable. But i'm sorry that the list needs to be scrollable due to requirement.

Comment: so try     `position: absolute;` instaed relative

Comment: Tested: Add position: absolute; z-index: -1 to .container, it is the case as using relative.

Comment: Found out the solution! Use position relative / absolute with z-index: 0 can prevent the autohide scrollbar float to top in IE 11. Thank you @לבנימלכה !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`z-index` work only with  `position:relative/absolute;`**

```
   container {
    position:relative; //or absolute
    z-index:0
}
```